# Set active class to php include menu

Tags: php

I have a menu using the following code,

```
<ol id="feature_list">
    <li><a href="index.php?action=profile" class="feature_current">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a ....></li>
</ol>
```

When clicked the same page is loaded and I use the following code to include the required php
file.

```
if (($_GET['action']) == 'profile') {
    include('profile.php');     }
}
```

Now I want to set active class 'feature_current' to menu dynamically based on the link clicked , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same way as you include the file:

```
<li><a href="...?action=profile" 
<?php if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='profile'){ 
echo 'class="feature_current"'; } ?>
>...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
  <a href="index.php?action=profile" class="feature_current
    <?php if ($_GET['action'] == 'profile') { echo ' active"'; } ?>
  ">
    Profile
  </a>
</li>
```

Elongate to show the code better, but use the `$_GET` in-line with the PHP to output a class, when necessary.

Your other option is to use javascript and look at the `location` variable and apply the class based on the link, but server-side solution is probably best.

Comment: why do u use () in this way ? `($_GET[..]) ? 'foor' : 'bar';` ok but for the whole sentence, where is the benefit ?

Comment: @Rufinus: I'm not sure I understand the question. I use an [in-line ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-111) just to make the output easier then `if { echo } else { echo }` -- EDIT I suppose given there's only one output, I can exempt it and use a single IF...

Comment: i know the in-line ternary operator. but i never saw this capsuling. i just use `echo ('whatever'==$foo) ? 'true' : 'false';` instead of `echo ('whatever'==$foo ? 'true' : 'false');` i just wonder if there is a difference.

Comment: @Rufinus: No, just preference. I tend to keep the parenthesis wrapping the entire condition instead of just the logic (personal preference maybe, but I like to know that the closing parenthesis is the end of the statement, not just the condition.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$actionClass = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

switch($actionClass){

default:
$actionClass = 'featured_content';
break;

case 'profile':
$actionClass = 'profile-class-name';
break;
  etc....
}
```

and the html

```
   <ol id="feature_list">
        <li><a href="index.php?action=profile" class="<?php echo $actionClass;?>">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a ....></li>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY SIMPLE solution: you can use PHP to grab from the URL the value you wish and inserting the grabbed value at a jQuery code like:

```
$('.#').addClass('active');
```

Where "#" is the value grabbed from the URL.
For example:

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){';
if(intval($_GET['PageID']) > 0) {
    $from_url = intval($_GET['PageID']);
    } else {
        if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $from_url = $_GET['action'];
        } else {
        $from_url = 'index';
        }
    }
echo '
    $(\'' . $from_url . '\').addClass(\'active\');
    });
</script>';

?>
```

Also explained [here](http://eduardomarques.com/snippets/jquery-active-links/).

Comment: It would be better if you could include an explanation of your solution in this answer.  Then you could keep the link to your website in your answer as a way to allow people to find out more information.  But the answer given here should be sufficient enough to solve without requiring using the link (in case the link goes down).